# emulate two column table inside div in pure css

Tags: css, list, multiple-columns

so basically this is my layout. 3 row div (header content and footer)

what i want to do is emulate inside the content div a table format so i can display info as such

```
picture1  detail1
picture2  detail2
picture3  detail3
```

there are at least 10 rows of such info. doesn't have to be picture but can also be text

picture div will be about 150px while detail will be the rest. for the sake of example lets say 600px wrapper

i tried a few setups but it didn't come out the way i desired. in a table this would be a cinch but i would like a pure css table-less layout

something i tried but doesn't come out into columns

HTML
    
    picture
    item 1 goes here
    
     
    
    picture2
    item2 goes here

CSS

```
.itemwrapper{width:600px;}

picture{width:150px;float:left;}
item{width:450px;float:left;}
.clear {clear:both;}
```

please tell me how i can do this. jsfiddle example here - http://jsfiddle.net/4qvz220b/1/

table would be as simple as

```
<table width="500">
<tr>
<td width="150">picture1</td>
<td width="450">item1 goes here</td>
</tr>
<tr>   
<td>
<td width="150">picture2</td>
<td width="450">item2 goes here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

can someone point me in the right direction, i don't know much about css except what i can do through trial and error. the solution must be cross browser compatible css with no js or hacks etc.

please note that this is not to layout the entire page but just a two column content inside another div. if a unordered list can be used instead somehow, please let me know.

Comment: I think, you forgot to add a `.` before classes names, you could  try `.picture` and `.item` instead of `picture` and `item`. DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/4qvz220b/2/

Comment: that was mighty stupid of me. thanks. let me see if it works to my desired requirement. usually the two divs do not align properly if the heights are not the same. let me check and get back to you.

Comment: great. worked perfectly when i added the content as in - http://jsfiddle.net/4qvz220b/4/

Comment: just an adendum, for each "row" that im emulating must i clear or this is not necessary

Comment: best clearfix solutions - http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ and http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got the structure right. You just need to use the right properties...

With css you can build the actual table structure using the `display` properties, as you have:

- `display: table`
- `display: table-row`
- `display: table-cell`

And other, such as `header` and `footer`, if you use the right syntax.

So a basic example (without any style customization) would be something like:

[**FIDDLE LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/4qvz220b/3/)

```
<div class="mainwrapper">
    <div class="itemwrapper">
        <div class="picture">picture</div>
        <div class="item">item 1 goes here</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="itemwrapper">
        <div class="picture">picture2</div>
        <div class="item">item2 goes here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.mainwrapper {
    display: table;
}

.itemwrapper {
    display: table-row;
}

.picture, .item {
    display: table-cell;
}
```